# yeoman and rxjs - unrecognized import path

Tags: javascript

I started project using Yeoman generator and i want use RxJS. I use js only. I can't import Observable class. I tried

```
import {Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and I'm getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "rxjs/Observable.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need webpack. Gary Simon explains it very clearly in this tutorial https://coursetro.com/posts/code/147/How-to-Install-RxJS---Setting-up-a-Development-Environment

Answer (score 0):

You can also use parcel to handle this issue quickly, check out the simple installation guide [here](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/)